# How can I check something every 5 min and break check when needed?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-7

In MainPage.xaml.cs I have created a BackgroundWorker. This is my code:

```
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgw_DoWork);
            bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgw_RunWorkerCompleted);
            bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            bgw.CancelAsync();

            base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        }

        void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((sender as BackgroundWorker).CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;

                return;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(1000*60*5); // 5 minutes
        }

        void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled || (sender as BackgroundWorker).CancellationPending)
                return;

        /* the work thats needed to be done with the ui thread */

        (sender as BackgroundWorker).RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

But this does not work. How can i properly stop the backgroundworker when navigating to another page?

Comment: This might sound silly, but why don't you use Timer instead?

Comment: guess the correct timer for windows phone is DispatcherTimer.

Answer (score 1):

Create a signal such as `ManualResetEvent`.

```
ManualResetEvent _evStop = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

Instead of doing `Thread.Sleep()`, wait on your event object for your desired "delay" time.

```
_evStop.WaitOne(1000*60*5, false);
```

When you want to stop processing early, raise the signal on your event object.

```
_evStop.Set();
```

When the event is signalled, your WaitOne will return early.  Otherwise, it will time out after your specified amount of time.